# Migrating this question killed the chances of getting a response

Tags: discussion, migration

I asked [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/181672/why-is-outlook-for-android-using-a-weird-from-address) 
here last week. It was quickly migrated to Android Enthusiasts and since moving has seen very few views, no answers and no comments. The AE site has so few members (3500 vs 13K for SU), it will never get looked at. While I realize AE is a more specific site, I feel like this will get a better response on Super User.  Can I bring it back?

Comment: From [help center](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic): "*[do not ask about] electronic devices, media players, cell phones or **smart phones**, except insofar as they interface with your computer,*". Unless you can state that the issue is unrelated to Android, then it's more appropriate on [android.se]

Comment: I think it directly related to the Outlook software, not the phone.  Does that help?

Comment: If it was the software you focussing on the Android app for most of the question doesn't sound like it's not an Android app question, unless you've tested it on other platforms and gotten the same result

Comment: Can you bring it back to Superuser?  The problem is either with Outlook.com or Outlook on Android.  I don't see a question that falls within the scope of Superuser honestly.

Answer (score 5):

Quite simply your question is off topic for Super User. You have stated that it works fine in Outlook.com, a Webapp, but that your trouble is with Outlook for Android, an Android app.

Super User is for PC applications and your question is explicitly stated as being off topic by the [help centre on both counts](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic).

> is not about …
>
> - **websites or web services** like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress,
> - electronic devices, media players, **cell phones** or smart phones, except insofar as they interface with your computer,

The relative community sizes are not taken into account to the site topicality rules. That you would prefer your question on our site is irrelevant when your question shows no hint that your problem is with a program on a PC, a browser to website interaction or even anything related to a PC. Your problem is either specific to a Webapp, which you say works fine and so is not a problem, or it is with limitations in an Android app.

Unless you can edit your question to fit the topicality guidelines for this site then it cannot be reopened here.

As it stands your question is off topic here and the only worthwhile option for you *was* for it to be migrated. The only other option was for it to be closed here as being off topic.